# Has more columns than specified in the column list for cross apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, cross-apply

Here is my query, where I am trying to get the records in JSON format.
I don't understand why am I getting the error stating:

> l2 has more columns than specified in the column list for cross apply

and also error:

> l3 has more columns than specified in the column list for cross apply

```
SELECT
    l1.ID,
    l1.root_id,
    l1.level_id,
    d1.name,
    questionnare_data = (SELECT l1.ID, l1.level_id, categories = l2.subcategories FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
FROM  [951278].[grc].[category] l1
INNER JOIN [951278].[grc].[category_data] d1
ON l1.ID=d1.category_id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT l2.ID, level_id, d2.name, l3.subcategories
    FROM [951278].[grc].[category] l2
    INNER JOIN [951278].[grc].[category_data] d2
    ON l2.ID=d2.category_id
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT l3.ID, l3.level_id, d3.name
        FROM [951278].[grc].[category] l3
        INNER JOIN [951278].[grc].[category_data] d3
        ON l3.ID=d3.category_id
        WHERE l3.root_id = l2.ID
        FOR JSON PATH
    ) l3(subcategories)
    WHERE l2.root_id = l1.ID
    FOR JSON PATH
) l2(subcategories)
WHERE l1.ID = 1;
```

Where did I go wrong. Please help

Comment: @AlwaysLearning `FOR JSON PATH` combines the `SELECT l2.ID, level_id, d2.name, l3.subcategories` to a single column

Comment: @AlwaysLearning So how can I modify my query

Comment: @MartinSmith So how can I modify my query

Comment: @MartinSmith yep, missed that.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? I see it in intellisense but the query actually executes fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRdYv.png

Comment: @MartinSmith Even I see it fine in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0499e21e2c25bba3d0b80fcaa373da5 but when I try to execute in my localhost I am getting this error

Comment: If you are actually getting this as a runtime error rather than an intellisense warning check that you are on the latest CU